# ** ionic build --prod ** is not working when i going to build for production

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

When i tried `ionic build --prod` , not able to make on production, due to this, **Vendor.js** `file size` is **8.6MB** which is taking to much time on loads and getting the attached image **error**.
[image: This error i am getting.]

Comment: Please add your log as a text to the message. It has answer to your question but it's not fair to force others to manually type the text from screenshot. For you it's simple copy-paste. Use `code` formatting.

Answer (score 2):

The error you are seeing above is not about the file size.

The error is due to duplicate declaration of the Page (Wrong Lazy Load config). You have the Pages as modules and have declared them both in app.module and in the Page's own module. You must declare them at only one place. (ArchivedConversationsPage)

Do that and this issue will be resolved -- you will get a prod build.

Comment: I fixed as you said but still getting Errors. FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory. i went in advanced system setting-> Environment variables Add New "NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=6144"  but still getting same error[JavaScript heap out of memory].I have 8GB RAM system.

Comment: This is unrelated to the original question - may be you should post a new question for this and accept the answer that helped resolve the duplicate definition error